# processing multiple images in sequence in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to build the code using python, for which I need to process at least 50 images. So how should I read the images one by one and process it. Is it possible using a loop and do i need to create a separate database for this or just saving all the images in separate file will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written some code may statisfy your requirement.

```
import glob
import os,sys 
import cv2


## Get all the png image in the PATH_TO_IMAGES
imgnames = sorted(glob.glob("/PATH_TO_IMAGES/*.png"))

for imgname in imgnames:
    ## Your core processing code 
    res = propress(imgname)

    ## rename and write back to the disk
    #name, ext = os.path.splitext(imgname)
    #imgname2 = name+"_res"+ext
    imgname2 = "_res".join(os.path.splitext(imgname))
    cv2.imwrite(imgname2, res)
```

Comment: Thank you @Silencer, but having some trouble in writing the files back to the disk. It is showing following error:
'File "C:\Python36\Doc\test\A1.py", line 28, in <module>
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(images)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 223, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list'

Comment: I cannot figure out what's wrong without your code.

Comment: hey! it worked, the new line which you added to the code. thanks @Silencer

Answer (score 0):

The task consists of following steps,

1. Having the images in a directory e.g. `foo/`
2. Getting the list of all images in the foo/ directory
3. Lopp over the list of images

   3.1. `img = cv2.imread(images(i),0)`

   3.2. `ProcessImage(img)` #Run an arbitrary function on the image

   3.3. filename = 'test' + str(i) +'.png'

   3.4. `cv2.imwrite(filename, img)`
4. End of the loop